# HTML5 / CSS3 template for web app

Tags: templates, web-applications, html, css

I am loooking for a good looking layout (template) for a web app, preferably in HTML5/CSS3 and preferably layout like the one pictured below. If that is not possible, then a layout that could easily be changed to a layout like this:
[image]

I have (of course) used a lot of time to see if I could find it/google it myself, but haven't found much else than Themeforest and the like - and haven't found the right thing there.

Am ready to spend good money on it, so it is more a matter of finding the right thing than the price.

Project start is Monday, so I cannot go to a design agency as that will take too long, so basically I need a paid or free template that we can later customize.

A simple layout would be sufficient, but a layout with nice design, nicely styled forms, buttons etc. would be preferable.

Any help on where to find it would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you looking for help with the layout or someone to make the layout for you?

Comment: He's looking for a premade, already coded _design_.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for responding. reisio is right, I am looking for already coded design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xJE53/1/

(I used min-height to simulate the main area being populated with content)

Comment: Šime, thanks so much for coding that. Is it CSS2 or 3? Thanks again :)

Comment: @rassom All properties except `overflow-y` are CSS2. Note that IE6 to IE8 have limited CSS2 support, so you have to check how this looks in those browsers. (I only have and care about IE9 here, so I cannot check for you)

Comment: OK, thanks very much Šime. Appreciate you taking the time to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Easy-peasy japanese :) Anyway if you want a fully css3 layout you should look [this implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-layout-20090402/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <style>
   #content {
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%;
   }

   #menu {
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 20%;
   }

   #footer {
    clear: left;
    height: 15%;
   }

   #header {
    height: 15%;
   }

   body {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
   }

   body > div {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-bozing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
   }

   input {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 7px;
   }

   input:hover {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 247, 1);
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id = "header">Header</div>
  <div id = "menu">Menu</div>
  <div id = "content">Content</div>
  <div id = "footer">Footer</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

### ***Preview***

[image: Rendered Page]

Comment: VERY nice of you 2x2p1p. Appreciate it! I am not super CSS shark - is the code you pasted CSS2 or CSS3? If the latter, I will definately go with your code unless I find something with more design - ie. like I wrote, with designed buttons, nicely designed/styled form fields etc. 

Do you - or do anyone else - have a full template (or a link for one) ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Wow I misunderstood, the code is just the front page. Css is pretty easy, you can handle that. I ll help you onemore time with the forms.

Answer (score 1):

What about [52Framework](http://52framework.com/)?

Comment: Thanks, Knu. I did have a look at 52Framework and while it does contain some nice things, it doesn't really have the graphic layout which is what I would be prefer.